# keras.load_model() incorrect loading with gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So i have 2 enviroments in Anaconda.

And 1 of this load correctly my pre-trained model. [This is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YJXf.png). But this env has no tf-gpu.

But second env with tf-gpu load incorrectly. [This is not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81rEQ.png).

```
First env:
-tensorflow == 2.5.0
-keras == 2.4.3

Second env:
-tensorflow == 2.4.0
-tensorflow-gpu == 2.4.0
-keras == 2.6.0
-cuda == 11.0
-cudnn == 8.2.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. If you use tensorflow <= 2.4.0. You can't train your pre-trained models, because in tensorflow == 2.5.0 add this function. So update your tensorflow and you can train your model after training.